# RAILS Algolia How to get the Ruby Object, Instantsearch.js

Tags: ruby-on-rails, algolia, instantsearch.js

I implemented Algolia's instantsearch on my Rails app. I use it to display a list of product as search results.

For the instant search implementation I followed Algolia's guide.

I created an Index called Products (on my Algolia account). It has a name, url, image, and an id (+ an objectID given by Algolia).

My application.js file with the Algoli search widgets:

```
    var search = instantsearch({
  // Replace with your own values
  appId: "1JJ5DY0CLA",
  apiKey: 'e24882443747d61c496efc4e17288a36', // search only API key, no ADMIN key
  indexName: 'Idea',
  urlSync: true
});


search.addWidget(
  instantsearch.widgets.searchBox({
    container: '#search-input',
    placeholder: 'Search for growth ideas',
    poweredBy: true
  })
);

search.addWidget(
  instantsearch.widgets.hits({
    container: '#hits',
    hitsPerPage: 10,
    templates: {
      item: getTemplate('hit'),
      empty: getTemplate('no-results')
    }
  })
);

search.start();

function getTemplate(templateName) {
  return document.querySelector('#' + templateName + '-
template').innerHTML;
}
```

The code inside my index.html.erb view looks like this:

```
# Comment: this is the code to structure each result sent by the API
<script type="text/html" id="hit-template">
    <div class="product">
       <div class="product-title">  
          <h3>{{title}}</h3>
       </div>
       <div class="product-link">
          <%= link_to "Voir", CGI::unescape(product_path("
          {{objectID}}")) %>
       </div>
  </div>
```

Here is the result sent by Algolia (got it from the browser), don't know how to get the result variable inside the view/controller.

```
"hits": [
    {
      "id": 1881,
      "name": "FOULARD NOA PRINT OFF WHITE/TERRA/GERANIUM",
      "female": true,
      "category": "Accessoires",
      "brand_id": 7,
      "url": "https://www.ekyog.com/foulard-noa-print-off-white/terra/geranium.html",
      "photos": [
        "https://www.ekyog.com/Imagestorage/imagesSynchro/556/790/e86cffa2bbbeea83a9d4bb7de0bbd5c368a6c9dd_B-FOU-288-P219.jpg",
        "https://www.ekyog.com/Imagestorage/imagesSynchro/556/790/4644f21ce6e8ddf8a1b3af053264c2c5429567d5_B-FOU-288-P219-CONF1.jpg"
      ],
      "price_cat": "0€ - 50€",
      "subcategory": "Echarpes & Foulards",
      "price_cents": 3400,
      ....
```

I can get the link like that :

```
<%= link_to "Voir",  CGI::unescape(product_path("{{objectID}}")) %>
```

How can I retrieve the ruby object in my view ?

I try to do it :

```
<% product = Product.find("{{objectID}}") %>
```

or

```
<% product = Product.find("{{id}}") %>
```

But it's not working. How get I get the object inside the view/controller ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your ERB code is only evaluated at page render time.
Your `link_to` will work because this is just generating a string (e.g. `/products/{{objectID}}`), that will later be updated by the front-end.

You can't use those variables to actually do something with them using Ruby code. Indeed, with `instantsearch.js`, you're dynamically retrieving the results without reloading the page, which means that you'll only have access to a JavaScript context.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, so I have to do it using REACT ?

Comment: Your hit template is already using a template engine, called Hogan : https://mustache.github.io/mustache.5.html .